# Explicitly create addition operator in Java with constraints. Unsolvable?

Tags: java, recursion

As practice to learn recursion, I quested myself to explicitly recreate the addition operator with an input of two integers (including positive, negative, and zero values). However, the catch is I have set some hard constraints on myself.

***Constraints***

*Use of recursion and conditionals*

*Cannot use iteration (Ex: `for`, `while`, etc.)*

*Cannot use implicit iteration (Ex: `++`, `--`)*

*Cannot use a mathematical operators (Ex: `+`, `-`, `/`, etc.)*

*Cannot use shorthand assignments (Ex: `+=`, `-=`, `/=`, etc.)*

***Code***

Here is the code I have:

```
/**
 * Create explicit addition with given constraints.
 * 
 * @author CodingBash
 *
 */
public class Addition {

    /**
     * Function call
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstNumber = 3;
        int secondNumber = 6;

        // firstNumber + secondNumber
        int result = add(firstNumber, secondNumber);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    /**
     * Function recursively takes a number from 'giver' one at a time and
     * "gives"/"adds" it to 'receiver'. Once nothing more to "give" ('giver'
     * ==0), then return the number that received the values, 'receiver'.
     * 
     * @param receiver
     *            - parameter that accumulates (++ each layer)
     * @param giver
     *            - parameter that dissipates (-- each layer)
     * @return
     */
    public static int add(int receiver, int giver) {
        if (giver != 0) {
            return add(directionalIncrement(receiver, giver),
                    directionalIncrement(giver, -giver));
        } else {
            return receiver;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Increments (or decrements) the 'number' based on the sign of the
     * 'direction'
     * 
     * @param number
     *            - base number that is incremented or decremented
     * @param direction
     *            - number that determines if base number increments or
     *            decrements. If positive, increment. If negative, decrement.
     * @return
     */
    public static int directionalIncrement(int number, int direction) {
        int incrementalValue = (direction > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        return add(number, incrementalValue); // StackOverflowError
    }
}
```

The code produces a `StackOverflowError` at `return add(number, incrementalValue);`. Although, if the statement is replaced with `return number + incrementalValue`, the code runs exactly as intended with any variation of integer inputs. However, the change deviates from the constraint.

Is this task with the certain constraints unsolvable? If so, please explain how so. If not, please provide a solution within the given constraints preferably similar to my implementation.

Comment: How do you think your adding works?

Answer (score 1):

You enter the add function with `giver!=0`, then the `directionalIncrement(giver, -giver)` is called returning you a new value for `giver` which is 1 or -1, so not 0. Then you call the `add` with `giver!=0` again. Yes, this will cause a `StackOverFlowError` since it is calling `add` over and over again without ever returning to the original call. The code has to return to the original call to be able to process the contents of the stack. Your code just keeps adding to the stack.

Comment: In other words, the recursion never meets its *stop condition*.